# Intercept Windows access to thumbcache.db file

Tags: database, windows, security, caching, thumbnails

I want to create a piece of software that intercepts the explorer's access to the thumbnail cache. The software shall accept the explorer's requests and return possitive or negative results depending on a certain condition (e.g. is a drive mounted and for what file is the thumbnail requested). Furthermore the mounted drive contains a key to decrypt the custom thumbnails. If the drive or key file isn't available, the tool shall just tell the explorer that no thumbnail exists.

My problems:

- Which language is capable of intercepting such request? Is there some standard way of doing this? Can I just fake an entire file? E.g. all access to the file are routed to my application?
- Is the file format of thumbnailcache.db documented? Does explorer pull the entire file into memory? What is the smartest way to intercept the communication?

I am thankful for any hints, even if they are only a partial solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding intercepting access - you need to create/use [filesystem filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx). You can write your own or use our [CallbackFilter](http://www.eldos.com/cbflt/) product.

With filter driver you can deny requests, modify them, serve fake file contents etc.